# problem related to the IValidatableObject interface built-into .NET 4 to implement a custom validation method on a class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

i m using the below code in c#

```
_validator = new CustomerValidator();
if (_validator.Exists(Name))
     yield return new ValidationResult("Already present");
```

which wokr well in case of insert query .it just check the user already thr..i use the above code in my model class.but in update case i struck becuse again i chk the modelstateisvalid in action controler..

so how can i getrid from this problem

model class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using BLL.Models;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace BLL.Models
{
    public class Test : IValidatableObject
    {
        public virtual int ID { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual string Age { get; set; }
        public virtual string City { get; set; }
        public virtual string Country { get; set; }
        public virtual string image { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime DOB { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime DOJoining { get; set; }
        private CustomerValidator _validator;

        public virtual IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            _validator = new CustomerValidator();
            if (_validator.Exists(Name))
                yield return new ValidationResult("Already present");

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
                yield return new ValidationResult("Name is complusry");
            if (DateTime.Compare(DOB, DOJoining) > 0)
                yield return new ValidationResult("Dob be less than DoJoining");
        }
    }
}
```

controller func for update

```
public JsonResult UserUpdate(Test obj,bool fvar)
{
    flag = false;
    ModelState.Remove("Name");
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        obj.image = obj.Name;
        QueryResult Query = new QueryResult();
        Query = ServiceTest.Update(obj);
        ViewBag.Message = "Updated";
    }

    ViewBag.Message = "Try Again we new credentials";

    return Json(obj);
}
```

controller for insert

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult insert(Test obj, bool fvar)
{
    flag = true;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        obj.image = obj.Name;
        QueryResult Query = new QueryResult();
        Query = ServiceTest.insert(obj);
        ViewBag.Message = "inserted";
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Already Present";
    }
    return View();
}
```

in insert it work fine beacuse i have to chk the user already ..but in update it again chk the CustomerValidator  but how i get rid it of

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to change your IValidatableObject.Validate method to check the ID:

```
if (ID == 0 && _validator.Exists(Name))
                yield return new ValidationResult("Already present");
```

That way the name check will only take place on inserts.

If you are allowing the user to change the Name property on update, then you will need to store the old name in a hidden field and change the code to something like:

```
if ((ID == 0 || Name != OldName) && _validator.Exists(Name))
                yield return new ValidationResult("Already present");
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to handle this is to use view models. So here you have two different actions each having a specific validation requirements and specific properties that needs to be bound from the view => write two view models:

```
public class InsertViewModel : IValidatableObject
{
    ... only properties required for insert
    ... IValidatableObject rules for insert
}

public class UpdateViewModel : IValidatableObject
{
    ... only properties required for update
    ... IValidatableObject rules for update
}
```

and then:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Insert(InsertViewModel obj) { ... }

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(UpdateViewModel obj) { ... }
```

[AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) could then help you with the mapping between your view models and the actual models you would be passing to your repository.